How to save and load a list of ints
I have a list of ints, how do I save and load them to a file? Here's my code for saving:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class Data : MonoBehaviour
{
    public INVENTORY inv;

    public static int story;

    public void LoadGame()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath
                       + "/data.file"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file =
                       File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath
                       + "/data.file", FileMode.Open);
            SaveData data = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            story = data.story;

            Debug.Log("Game data loaded!");
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError("There is no save data!");
    }

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath
                     + "/data.file");
        SaveData data = new SaveData();

        data.story = story;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
        Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
    }
}

[Serializable]
class SaveData
{
    public int story;
}

As you can see I only am saving one int right now, but I wanna save a list of ints I have. It would look like this
public List<int> integers = new List<int>();

Either a list or an array would work, I just wanna save it and load it

What problem do you encounter when you use List for story instead of int?

STOP USING BinaryFormatter ! You can use Newtonsoft Json.NET (Unity package: com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json) instead

Don't use BinaryFormatter. It's deprecated and will not work with .NET 8.0 or later.
Also, for saving small pieces of data, some structured format like json or xml is to be preferred over a binary format, because it's much easier to handle and to debug. You can use something like
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
File.WriteAllText("savefilename.json", serialized);

and
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("savefilename.json");
var data = (SaveData)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(fileContent, typeof(SaveData));

That even automatically adjusts to any changes you make to your data structures. So you don't have to update your save method each time you add a new property.
